# Automatically filter out rows that don't meet a condition in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I have a database already in use and I can't really change it. On this database I use a "soft delete": instead of actually deleting a record, I just modify a flag (e.g. setting `del=1`).

I don't use the GEDMO template (SoftDelete) but I want the same functionality. Currently when I use QueryBuilder/find functions, they return records with `del=1`. Same idea on association entities' functions; I have to check every time if `del=0`.

Is there a way to automatically filter out records with flag `del=1`, unless it's explicitly requested?

Comment: I've just tidied up your grammar a little and hopefully made the question a little more easy to understand. Please jump in an edit if I've made anything incorrect. I've also tried to make the title more specific, again edit this if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably can use doctrine filters:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html
http://www.michaelperrin.fr/2014/07/25/doctrine-filters/

to disable:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html#disabling-enabling-filters-and-setting-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Another perspective is to make your code more readable and perhaps easier by doing something like this:

```
$entity = $em->getRepository("MyBundle:Entity")->findBy(['del' => 0]);
```

This adds very little code and is obvious to any reader what you're up to.

#### Edit

Alternatively, if your database & privileges permit (e.g., root in MySQL) you can create a view that contains only `del=0` records. For MySQL, here's the [CREATE VIEW doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html). Doctrine permits the use of views.